# Track refresh of a browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an web application that is built using MVC. Now after one page gets loaded, every inner activity is done using jquery ajax data loading. So I am filling the data again in the same container using ajax. Now if user wants to click on refresh button of the browser I want to load the same data that is being loaded by last ajax call. Not the whole page refresh using the URL mentioned in the browser URL (because the data that will be returned is data loaded first time the page loaded).
Is it possible to do anyhow, using javascript or jquery or any server side methodologies?
I am using .NET MVC 4.0 in the application.

Comment: You need to persist the _current state/view_ of your page. Save the last AJAX call (i.e. the last called URL) or some internal description of the data that has been loaded. Save this on every change. You can use the `sessionStorage` of the client's browser. On page load you can check if any data has been saved for the current page; if so, just get the data according to the description you saved.

Comment: If I request any other new URL then will also get previous sessionStorage data and accordingly that will return wrong data to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the possible solutions,

1. HTML5 has introduced history.pushState() & history.popState() - **[Check here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method)**
2. Jquery plugins could be used - **[Check here...](http://www.sitepoint.com/history-back-button-plugins/)**
3. Manually saving the state of every page/ajax calls in Javascript and using the same on page
   load, which needs more effort for accomplishing

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it using pushState() or popState()?

Comment: You need to push the url/state of every ajax call to the history API. Refer these [1](http://html5demos.com/history#view-source) & [2](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/gallery/fer.html) for sample code. If you need any specific help related to your application, please provide more details with code.

You could accept my answer, I am greedy about reputation ;)